# Как оптимизировать запросы к API

Tags: php, jquery, архитектура, логика

Делаю для себя, сайт - вывод валют из разных банков, калькулятор для конвератации. И вот возникло несоколько вопросов, как правильно делать.

Во первых, данные о курсе беру с API другого сайта, каждый раз отправляя запрос, что делает загрузку сайта очень долгой, как оптимизировать этот процес ? 
Записовать данные в БД каждые n минут их обновлять, а после выводить пользователю ?
Или нагрузки никак не избежать ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, обновляя данные по cron/планировщику вы значительно разгрузите сайт. Один запрос раз в пять минут выполнить менее накладно, чем загрузка и разбор данных для 200 посетителей одновременно. Кроме того, загрузка, ожидание будет проходить в фоне для cron-процесса, посетители смогут получать информацию сразу в подготовленном виде (например, из локальной базы данных).